# differentiation of vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

what would be the differentiation of this equation :-

$$f(A) = \sum_i \left \| Y_{i} - AB_{i} \right \|^2 + \left \| A - A_\text{constant} \right \|^2$$

wrt to $A$.

where $Y$ is a column vector and $B$ is column vector and $A$ is a matrix .
PS: $i$ will lie in a finite range.

Comment: You need specify your question. Are you looking for a directional derivative or for the Jacobian? In any case, the answer will depend on the norms you use...(?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [derivation of vector norm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475658/derivation-of-vector-norm)

Answer (score 2):

If we assume Ferrobenious norm in equation :  $ f(A)=∑_{i}∥Y_{i}−AB_{i}∥^2_F+∥A−A_{constant}∥^2_F$ then it can be written as $ f(A)=∑_i trace((Y_i−AB_i)(Y_i−AB_i)^T)+trace((A−A_{constant})(A−A_{constant})^T)= ∑_i trace(Y_i Y_i^T−AB_iY_i^T -Y_i B_i^T A^T+AB_i B_i^T A^T)+trace(AA^T−AA_{constant}^T-A_{constant} A^T−A_{constant}A_{constant}^T) $
Now you can compute  $ \frac{\mathrm \partial}{\mathrm \partial A}f(A)= ∑_i (-2 Y_i B_i^T-2 AB_i B_i^T)+ (2A −2A_{constant}^T) $ 
If you want know on how to take  differentiation with respect to matrices or vectors, you can  see matrixcookbook.com which has book with the same name.